# Pygame, my circle turns to a rect after I stored it in a variable, how do I prevent that from happening

Tags: pygame, data-conversion

I need to store a Circle in a variable but after I've done that it has turned into a rect

```
circle_1 = pygame.draw.circle(screen, (0, 0, 0), (300, 300), 30)
Print(circle_1)
```

the print returns

```
<rect(270, 270, 60, 60)>
```

but I can't work with that.
My circle is predefined but it won't show it on the canvas, here is an example of the problem

```
> import pygame, sys
> 
> 
> pygame.init() screen = pygame.display.set_mode((600, 600)) 
> predefined_circle = pygame.draw.circle(screen,(0, 0, 0),(300, 300), 30)
> 
> def update():
>     screen.fill((200, 0, 0))
>     while 1:
>         for event in pygame.event.get():
>             if event.type == pygame.QUIT: sys.exit()
>         # It shows my circle if I dirctly tip pygame.draw.circle(screen,(0, 0, 0),(300, 300), 30) into it
>         predefined_circle
>         pygame.display.update()
> 
> update()
```

So that you can better relate to what I'm trying to achieve here is the code of what I'm doing but it is not necessary to read as I've already tried to explain it as best as I can above.
Please note the comments should explain everything that the block of code below it is doing.

```
# Creating the canvas which can paint any wanted Object from another class
class Canvas:
# Initialising the screen and setting all needed variables
def __init__(self, painting):
    pygame.init()
    self.screen_size = (600, 600)
    self.background = (25, 255, 255)
    self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode(self.screen_size)
    self.paint = painting

# Let the user set the name of the canvas
def set_screen_name(self):
    return self.screen

# Draw the everything you want to
def update(self):
    # Paint the canvas
    self.screen.fill(self.background)
    # Make the game be quittable
    while 1:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT: sys.exit()

        # Draw the defined Circle and then update the Canvas
        # it only draws a circle if directly tip pygame.draw.circle(surface, color, position, radius)

        self.paint
        pygame.display.update()


# Draw any circle you like
class Cir:
# Get all the required Information's to Draw a circle
def __init__(self, canvas, what_color, position, radius, line=0):
    self.can = canvas
    self.color = what_color
    self.pos = position
    self.r = radius
    self.line = line
    self.cir = None

# Create the circle with the acquired Information's
def create(self):
    self.cir = pygame.draw.circle(self.can, self.color, self.pos, self.r, self.line)
    return self.cir


# So far there is no Surface for the Cir class
# And there is no Object that cloud be painted for the Canvas class
# I initialise a canvas instance without anything that needs to be painted
get_surface = Canvas(None)

# Now I can access set_screen_name from the Canvas class and give the surface a name
# Which the Cir class can now use as a surface
screen = get_surface.set_screen_name()

c1 = pygame.draw.circle(screen, (0,0,0), (300, 300), 30)
print(c1)

# I'm initialising a circle
init_circle = Cir(screen, (0, 255, 0), (300, 300), 30)

# Create the initialised circle
circle_1 = init_circle.create()

# Give the Canvas class the created circle
paint = Canvas(circle_1)

# Draw the circle
paint.update()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My `circle` turns to a `rect`.

Actually, no, it doesn't. As per the [documentation](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/draw.html) for those drawing functions, the intent of the calls is to *draw* something immediately, *not* to give you an object you can draw later:

> Draw several simple shapes to a Surface.

From analysis of your question, it sounds like you believe that you are storing the *act* of drawing the circle so that it can be done later. That is not the case. Instead, what you are doing is actually drawing the circle and saving the *result* of that drawing action - evaluating the result later on will not actually draw, or redraw, the circle.

So, if the `draw` function is not returning something for later drawing, what *is* it returning? That can also be found in the above-mentioned documentation:

> The functions return a ***rectangle*** representing the bounding area of changed pixels.

In other words, it's telling you the smallest rectangle that was changed by the drawing action - this will be a square with sides the same length as the diameter and centered around the same point.

Obviously, the authors of PyGame thought this information may be handy for some purpose, just not the purpose of redrawing the circle :-)

---

One way to do what you're trying to achieve would be to simply have a *function* to draw the "predefined" circle and call that instead of trying to evaluate the rectangle returned from a previous call.

Comment: *this information may be handy for some purpose* The purpose is to know which part of the screen was actually changed in a frame so you can update the screen more efficiently by not having to update the entire screen.